# FAB on RelativeLayout like in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I want to made view looking like this.

[image]

I have a problem with FAB placement. I want to place it on the center and bottom of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **FrameLayout** as a container like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--MARGIN WILL BE HALF OF HEIGHT OF FAB-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```